# NextJs TypeError

Tags: typescript, next.js, typeerror

```
TypeError: responseHeaders.getSetCookie is not a function
    at new ResponseCookies (webpack-internal:///(app-metadata-route)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/cookies/index.js:213:47)
    at new NextResponse (webpack-internal:///(app-metadata-route)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/response.js:40:22)
    at GET (webpack-internal:///(app-metadata-route)/./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-metadata-route-loader.js?page=%2Ffavicon.ico%2Froute&isDynamic=0!./src/app/favicon.ico?__next_metadata_route__:15:10)
    at G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62505
    at G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\trace\tracer.js:121:36
    at NoopContextManager.with (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@opentelemetry\api\index.js:1:7057)
    at ContextAPI.with (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@opentelemetry\api\index.js:1:516)
    at NoopTracer.startActiveSpan (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@opentelemetry\api\index.js:1:18086)
    at ProxyTracer.startActiveSpan (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@opentelemetry\api\index.js:1:18847)
    at G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\trace\tracer.js:110:107
    at NoopContextManager.with (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@opentelemetry\api\index.js:1:7057)
    at ContextAPI.with (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@opentelemetry\api\index.js:1:516)
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\trace\tracer.js:110:32)
    at G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:56147
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:330:14)
    at Object.wrap (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:37057)
    at G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53934
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:330:14)
    at Object.wrap (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:36635)
    at G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53896
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:330:14)
    at eD.execute (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53870)
    at eD.handle (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63748)
    at doRender (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1217:56)
    at cacheEntry.responseCache.get.incrementalCache.incrementalCache (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1446:34)
    at ResponseCache.get (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\response-cache\index.js:53:26)
    at DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1361:53)
    at G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:903:121
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\trace\tracer.js:94:20)
    at DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponents (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:903:41)
    at DevServer.renderPageComponent (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1600:35)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1638:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:826:25)
    at async DevServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:623:13)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (G:\groove-hub\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:728:17)
```

I have just initialised an nextjs typescript application, but the unknown error is occurring, Even when my app is empty

Comment: Sometimes this types error can happen because of browser extensions. Try it again by disabling extensions.

Comment: Same started to happen when I upgraded to latest next and node version.

Answer (score 8):

I got same error with Node 18.12.1 and next `==13.5.5`.
And it disappeared with next `==13.5.4` or with Node `18.18.2`.

So, updating your Node version or next version will solve this problem.

Comment: for me, it was breaking even with node 18.18.2, I had to downgrade next to 13.5.4

Answer (score 0):

I got that error, what I did was to upgrade to node 18.18.2 and delete the node_modules folder, the packaje.json file and run the npm run install, and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, using next `==13.5.5` and Node v19.1.0. Reverting back to next `==13.5.4` solved the problem. Thanks to @kaoru for the advice